# Javascript Quote Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just having a difficulty with my Javascript Slideshow:

For some reason when I load the website onto chrome it seems to not show the first quotation on the first slide. It only appears when I click the Preview / Next arrows or the dots at the bottom of the slideshow.

Please could someone provide a solution to enable me to display the first quotation as soon as I open up the website.

[image]

Code shown below:

```js
// JavaScript Document
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  height: 175px;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
    <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you code works fine in the snippet. if you hit the blue button it shows all slides. where on the page are you putting your javascript? in the <head>?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can see that, I just don't get why it isn't doing this on Dreamweaver. I've got the link for Javascript in the <Head> Section (<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>). The main code for Javascript is on a seperate Javascript File.

Comment: You need to put your javascript at the bottom of the <body> tag, right before the closing </body> tag. either that or put your code in an onload event listener.

Comment: That's worked. Fair play, thank you so much.

Comment: Do you think I can put 3 Quotes into one slide instead of just one? To do this do I need to create 3 div tags for each slide?